# Flutter TextFormField obscure text: hidden last letter after n second

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter app with a password textfield

```
TextFormField(
  obscureText: true,
)
```

I run the app on Android, the password is obscured, but it shows the last letter for a while, like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELTLf.png)

But when running the app on iOS, the last letter is hidden immediately so user can't see the last letter. However, I want it to be displayed last letter in the same way on Android.

How can i do it ?